# Inject interface in INotificationHandler MediatR

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, mediator

I am tryin to implement some MediatR *INotification* in my solution. 
My problem is that i cant figure out how to be able to inject an interface '*ISchemaRepository*' in one *INotificationHandler<>*. The MediatR and all classes below are in my ASP.NET Core project, and the *ISchemaRepository* is in a different .NET core class library, and the '*SchemaRepository*' is located in a different ASP.NET Core project. Basically what i want to achive is to get data from one db and insert into another db in another project.

I have been reading alot of articles concerning the MediatR but havnt found any examples on how to achive this. Is it even possible to inject an interface into a '*INotificationHandler<>*'?
I know i might be in deep water and i am still a bit of a rookie when it comes to programming.

When i run the application in its following state i get an exception:

*"An exception was thrown while activating λ:MediatR.INotificationHandler`1[[Facade.Application.Events.GetScheduleEvent, Facade, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]][] -> Facade.Application.Events.ScheduleEventHandler -> ServiceApi.Repository.SchemaRepository."*

I tried a couple of different solutions in my ApplicationModule and MediatorModule since my guess is that this is related to dependencyinjection. My best guess was to add

```
            builder.RegisterType<ScheduleEventHandler>()
            .As<ISchemaRepository>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

to my 'ApplicationModule' but then i get this exception on startup:

*"System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=The type 'Facade.Application.Events.ScheduleEventHandler' is not assignable to service 'Service.InternalResourceRepository.ISchemaRepository'.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.CreateRegistration(Guid id, RegistrationData data, IInstanceActivator activator, Service[] services, IComponentRegistration target) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Builder\RegistrationBuilder.cs:line 192
"*

This is my INotificationHandler<>:

```
    public class ScheduleEventHandler : INotificationHandler<GetScheduleEvent>
{
    private readonly ISchemaRepository _repository;
    public ScheduleEventHandler(ISchemaRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Task Handle(GetScheduleEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _repository.SeedSchedule();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

'GetScheduleEvent' is just an empty class declared with 'INotification'.

This is my 'MediatorModule':

```
    public class MediatorModule : Autofac.Module
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implementing the Mediator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder"></param>
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();            

        //Events
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ScheduleEventHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));

        builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
        {
            var componentContext = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return t => { object o; return componentContext.TryResolve(t, out o) ? o : null; };
        });

    }
}
```

As you can see i am using AutoFac. This is my ApplicationModule:

```
   public class ApplicationModule : Autofac.Module
{

    public string QueriesConnectionString { get; }

    public ApplicationModule(string qconstr)
    {
        QueriesConnectionString = qconstr;

    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.RegisterType<SchemaRepository>()
            .As<ISchemaRepository>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Appreciate all help i can get to solve this issue, if it can be solved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```cs
builder.RegisterType<ScheduleEventHandler>()
            .As<ISchemaRepository>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This says "When I resolve `ISchemaRepository` I want you to give me a new `ScheduleEventHandler` however:

```cs
public class ScheduleEventHandler : INotificationHandler<GetScheduleEvent>
```

`ScheduleEventHandler` doesn't implement `ISchemaRepository`. This isn't an Autofac thing, it's that you haven't implemented the interface.

For example, this would also fail:

```cs
var s = new ScheduleEventHandler();
var r = (ISchemaRepository)s;
```

You can only register types `As<T>` things that they implement/derive from.

If you want to troubleshoot the original exception, you need to look at the inner exception message.

```
An exception was thrown while activating λ:MediatR.INotificationHandler`1[[Facade.Application.Events.GetScheduleEvent, Facade, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]][] -> Facade.Application.Events.ScheduleEventHandler -> ServiceApi.Repository.SchemaRepository.
```

That's just the beginning. Keep reading, you should see *what that exception actually was* and possibly get some guidance as to how to fix it. Watch the Debug window, too, you may get some logs in there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looking at the inner exception i figured that the reason might be that my 'SchemaRepository' constructor takes a DbContext as parameter which is specific to my ServiceApi and have no connection to my FacadeApi(the api where i have my configuration). So when i try to inject 'SchemaRepository' as 'ISchemaRepository' it cannot resolve 'SchemaRepository' since it has no clue about the DbContext in the constructor. This is just a guess for now and ill will try to change some things and get back with the result.